# Copy a directory with xcopy/robocopy

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy, robocopy

I have a batch script which takes a directory path as parameter.
Inside the script, I'd like to copy this directory somewhere else.

For example, let the script parameter be "C:\Users\Raffaele\Foo" and the copy destination be "C:\Foe".
At the end, I'd like to have "C:\Foe\Foo".
Instead, the best I can get (both using xcopy and robocopy) is all files and subdirectories inside "Foo" copied into "Foe".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xcopy` is good enough for your requirements, read `HELP XCOPY` and `HELP CALL` and try

```
call :docopy c:\users\rafaele\foo c:\foe
goto :eof
:docopy
xcopy /S /E /I %1 %2\%~n1
goto :eof
```

the trick is to extract the directory name and use it to specify both source and destination directories

the `/S` flag copies the directories inside source

the `/E` flag creates directories in destination if they exist but are empty in source

the `/I` flag assumes the destination is a directory and creates it

Comment: I've thought something similar.

Since "C:\Users\Raffaele\Foo" is a variable path, how can I extract just the "Foo" part? Does exist a command like "basename" in Linux?

Comment: yes, you can use `%~n` to extract the name of the directory. Answer edited.